# Can a pseudo-element act as a block element without overlap?

Tags: html, css

I have three 50x50 colored blocks with content R, G, and B. Can these blocks be lined up vertically as would be expected if they were three `div` elements adjacent to each other?

[image]

It is possible if using a margin-bottom that is the same height of the red block but only if the red block does not contain any text. This is because the height of the text gets added to the height of the margin.

Is there a way to make this work with just `.red`, `.red::after`, and `.blue`?

```css
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

.demo-container {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 24px;
   border: solid 1px #d5d9dc;
}

.red {
   background: pink;
   display: block;
   min-width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
}

.red::after {
   content: "G";
   background-color: rgba(64, 255, 64, 0.5);
   display: block;
   min-width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
}

.blue {
   background-color: rgba(64, 64, 255, 0.5);
   display: block;
   min-width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="demo-container">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="red">R</div>
      <div class="blue">B</div>
   </div>
   <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `position: relative;height: 100px` to `.red` element.

then add: `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to `.red:after` element

```css
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

.demo-container {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 24px;
   border: solid 1px #d5d9dc;
}

.red {
   background: pink;
   display: block;
   min-width: 50px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
}

.red::after {
   content: "G";
   background-color: rgba(64, 255, 64, 0.5);
   display: block;
   min-width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0
}

.blue {
   background-color: rgba(64, 64, 255, 0.5);
   display: block;
   min-width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="demo-container">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="red">R</div>
      <div class="blue">B</div>
   </div>
   <br/>
</div>
```